# How to improve pseudo-random number generation by large truly random data?

Tags: algorithms, random-generation

### Question

Say I have access to a relatively large (but not huge) amount of truly random data, `D`, like 100 KiB of random bits from a hardware randomness source (just assume that it is larger than the seed or internal state of a typical PRNG).

How can I make the most of `D` to improve the quality of an unbounded number of pseudo-random samples, by doing more than just seeding it from some parts of `D` and discarding the rest?

An answer could either show a method to enhance an arbitrary pseudo-random sequence using `D`, or modify or combine existing algorithms.

### My ideas

One possibility I found was to just add the data to the entropy pool of [`dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random).  However, that assumes `dev/random` to exist on a system, which does not hold everywhere.  Also, I understand that it blocks when the available "entopy" is too small, which is not the kind of behaviour I'm after.  But if I'm mistaken, a description of its approach (which I don't understand) would be a valid answer.

Another thing that came to my mind was to just treat `D` as a BigInteger and run a regular PRNG algorithm on it, "chunking" down the outputs to word size again.  I don't know enough about the implemention of PRNGs to assess the feasibility of this, but I guess there will be performance hits due to all the prevented optimizations.

Or should I just seed as many instances of one PRNG as I can using `D`, and cycle through them? This might have huge constant memory overhead.

### More details about my assumptions

- By "not huge", I mean that I cannot be sure that the amount of data would suffice to just reinterpret little bits of it directly for each `rand` call that will happen, and it fits into memory without unreasonably penalties.
- I don't actually have a real use case -- this question just came across my mind.  It is actually a more theoretical thought; I guess adding `D` wouldn't improve a Monte Carlo algorithm very much in reality.

Answer (score 0):

I found [some code](https://github.com/cmcqueen/simplerandom/blob/17654c0e14d1fbce12c1a436367b98322d7865e6/c/simplerandom/simplerandom.c#L146) in the [simplerandom](https://github.com/cmcqueen/simplerandom) library that does this.  The proper term seems to be **mixing**.  Essentially, you just go through the data, XOR the PRNG state with it (taking into account peculiarities of the particular representation), and advance one step.  For example:

```
void simplerandom_shr3_mix(SimpleRandomSHR3_t * p_shr3, const uint32_t * p_data, size_t num_data)
{
    if (p_data != NULL)
    {
        while (num_data)
        {
            --num_data;
            p_shr3->shr3 ^= *p_data++;
            simplerandom_shr3_sanitize(p_shr3);
            simplerandom_shr3_next(p_shr3);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this can only work when you have a reasonably small state, not something like a several hundred bytes long Mersenne Twister.

---

Another related concept seems to be that of an [entropy pool](https://github.com/MartyMacGyver/PractRand/blob/master/doc/RNG_entropy_pools.txt), where you add arbitrary amounts of initial random data to a pool and use that once to seed the RNG.